# can I make update many in mongoose simpler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, simple-form

```js
 try {
 let ops = [];
 for (let obj of req.body || []) {
 ops.push({
 updateOne: {
 filter: { sku: obj.sku },
 update: {
             $inc: { stock: obj.stock },
             $set: {
 msp: obj.msp,
 mrp: obj.mrp,
 purchasePrice: obj.purchasePrice,
             },
           },
         },
       });
     }
 const product = await Variation.bulkWrite(ops, { ordered: true });
 res.status(200).json(product);
   }
```

I wish to reformat this code into a more readable and simpler could you help me?

Comment: Have you looked at the question before publishing it? Do you think that formatting the code like that is fine?

Comment: You have `try` without `catch` or `finally`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```js
const updateOperations = req.body.map(obj => {
  return {
    updateOne: {
      filter: {
        sku: obj.sku
      },
      update: {
        $inc: {
          stock: obj.stock
        },
        $set: {
          msp: obj.msp,
          mrp: obj.mrp,
          purchasePrice: obj.purchasePrice
        }
      }
    }
  };
});

try {
  const product = await Variation.bulkWrite(updateOperations, {
    ordered: true
  });
  res.status(200).json(product);
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
}
```

If you still face any issue. Please let me know